# Autocomplete isn't working in VS Code with React Components

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

After last update autocomplete has been broken: e.g. I can't see props for the component when I type Ctrl+Space. Import through "dot" isn't working also. I use ".js" extension. [No props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTYp3.png).
[No child components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EfqL.png)

Comment: Try to completely wipe your VSCode and re-install again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 hours I removed my project completely, then I cloned it from git and installed all dependencies (`yarn install`)... and it worked.